# Displaying webview on blank fragment

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I have 3 fragments, in each of them, I like to display the `WebView` of different URLs.

Example for fragment 1, on my xml file I added:

```
<WebView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
```

But in my java file i have this:

```
package com.domain.app;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebView;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class Fragment_Home extends Fragment {


    public Fragment_Home() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    }

}
```

I got the below code from another android project:

```
     myWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
     WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
     webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
     myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
     myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

which was in `MainActivity`, but how to put this code to my fragment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are doing this in a fragment you need to expand and reference the view that your webview will live in. So change your onCreate to this:

```
WebView myWebView;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    //creating and referencing our View
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home,container,false);

    //The key difference is we reference our view with the findViewById
    myWebView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webView);
    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    return view;
}
```

Here you can see that I changed it to actually reference the view you are pulling from which will allow you to update the components of that view. When manipulating components of a fragment you always need to reference the parent view.

Comment: Code works, but is removing top bar (navigation drawer)?

Comment: You just need to make sure that your fragment lives within the navigation drawer activity in your contentframe. Basically you are inflating your fragment but not including and replacing your main fragments.

Comment: Fragment_Home is first loaded, content_frame, is removed from app

Comment: So you don't want to remove content_frame. You would want to use FragmentTransactions to replace the view in your content_frame

Comment: Also if this has helped your webview issue please feel free to accept as answer.

Comment: I dont have content_frame, I have only fragment_home, fragment_about...
In main activity I have: FragmentTransaction ft=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.main_container,fragment_home);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116996/discussion-between-albastar-and-basic).